# 'str' object is not callable when passing variables into a procedure (Python 2)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a program that randomly generates a number and asks the user to guess it. However, whenever I run it I get the error "str" object is not callable when it calls the guess procedure passing in "guess, magic_number) form inside the intro procedure

```
import random

def new_guess(magic_number):
    guess = raw_input("Take a new guess!")
    guess(guess, magic_number)

def guess(guess, magic_number):
    if guess > magic_number:
        print "Your number is too high, try again!"
        new_guess(magic_number)
    if guess < magic_number:
        print "Your number is too low, try again!"
        new_guess(magic_number)
    if guess == magic_number:
        print "You win!"

def intro():
    print"Welcome to guess the number game! What number would you like to play to. Ex: 1000 would be 1-1000."
    limit = raw_input()
    print"Cool! I'm thinking of a number between 1-" + str(limit)
    magic_number = random.randint(1,int(limit))
        print"Guess a number!"
        guess = raw_input()
        guess(guess, magic_number)
intro()
```

Comment: Please post an actual copy/paste of the exception.

Comment: Notice that in `new_guess` you have a variable named 'guess'.  You then try to call a function named 'guess'.  I advise better naming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You named the string `guess` the same as the function `guess`. The interpreter goes with whatever was assigned most recently, masking the older references. To fix this, give every intended unique variable in a given namespace a unique name or reference, e.g. `user_guess`.

Comment: @user2080962 Be sure to mark as answer for Tigerhawk. There's a check mark on the side.